# Find sequence $(a_n)$ of positive reals such that $\sum a_n$ diverges but $\sum a_n/(\ln(\ln(n)))$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to find an example of a sequence $a_n >0$ such that its series $\sum a_n$ diverges, but when we consider  $$\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{a_n}{\ln(\ln(n))}$$ then this series is in fact convergent.

Any idea what to start with, what motivation would you use to find such a sequence?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I've addes some essential info.

Comment: @FilipWichrowski:  if we use  the variable $n$, use $\log$ instead of $\ln$. of course, both are correct, but $\log n$ looks fine than $\ln n$

Comment: but $\ln$ is the proper name for this $\log$

Comment: what would we like to see added to make this question better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $$a_n=\frac{1}{(n\, \ln n) \ln( \ln n)}$$ Then $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty a_n= \sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{(n \,\ln n) \ln( \ln n)} $$ diverges , but $$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{a_n}{\ln(\ln n)}= \sum_{n=3}^\infty\frac{1}{(n\,\ln n) \ln( \ln n)}. \frac{1}{\ln(\ln n)}=\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n \,\ln n [\ln (\ln n)]^2}< \infty$$

---

The convergence and divergence are follows from:

**Theorem 1**: Suppose $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \cdots \geq 0. $ Then $\sum a_n < \infty \iff \sum 2^k a_{2^k} < \infty$

**Theorem 2:** If $p>1$, then $$\sum \frac{1}{n\, (\ln n)^p} $$ converges, and diverges  otherwise

Comment: What led you to this form of $a_n$? And how to prove that $\sum a_n = +inf$?

Comment: see my answer again!

Comment: I suggest to use [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

Comment: @gimusi: I already mention that in my answer.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR That's fine sorry I didn't see that. Bye

Comment: Ok! no problem!

Comment: If this answers the question, I would say it's nice to accept it as an answer.

Comment: One more thing, if I may: I try to prove that $a_n$ diverges by comparing it to $\frac{1}{nln(n)ln(n)}$, but it coverages. Is there any different approach?

Comment: I think I got it - $\frac{ln(ln(n))}{ln(n)} < 1$ so the power of $ln(n)ln(ln(n)) < 1$, am I correct?